# Load twitter feeds via jquery ajax

Tags: ajax, api, jquery, twitter

How can I load the twitter below on via AJAX loaded page?

I have the twitter widget on a page called `twitter.php`

```
<script src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script>
<script>
new TWTR.Widget({
  version: 2,
  type: 'profile',
  rpp: 4,
  interval: 30000,
  width: 455,
  height: 563,
  theme: {
    shell: {
      background: '#e70e6f',
      color: '#ffffff'
    },
    tweets: {
      background: '#ccc8cc',
      color: '#ffffff',
      links: '#08a9cd'
    }
  },
  features: {
    scrollbar: false,
    loop: false,
    live: false,
    behavior: 'all'
  }
}).render().setUser('gtteam').start();
</script>
```

the html,

```
<a href="#" class="load">click to load</a> 

<div id="container"></div>
```

the jquery,

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('.load').click(function(){

             $('#container').load('twitter.php');
             return false;
        });

    });
```

the error message on firebug,

> TWTR is not defined [Break On This Error] (17 out of range 16)

How can I get around to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iframe is the solution I think:

iframe.php,

```
<iframe src="twitter.php" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" frameborder="0" 
style="border:0;height:600px;width:600px;" scrolling="no"   ></iframe>
```

twitter.php,

```
<script src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script>
<script>
new TWTR.Widget({
  version: 2,
  type: 'profile',
  rpp: 4,
  interval: 30000,
  width: 455,
  height: 563,
  theme: {
    shell: {
      background: '#e70e6f',
      color: '#ffffff'
    },
    tweets: {
      background: '#ccc8cc',
      color: '#ffffff',
      links: '#08a9cd'
    }
  },
  features: {
    scrollbar: false,
    loop: false,
    live: false,
    behavior: 'all'
  }
}).render().setUser('gtteam').start();
</script>
```

jquery,

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.load').click(function(){
        $('#container').load('iframe.php');
        return false;
    });

});
```

Works perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to avoid using an iframe you should be able to add the widget.js call to your master page  and then add a holding div and the id parameter to the twitter call and it should work.

```
// stick this in your index.html page <head>
<script src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script>

// on the page called via ajax

<div id="twtr-widget"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
new TWTR.Widget({
  version: 2,
  type: 'profile',
  rpp: 6,
  interval: 6000,
  width: 300,
  height: 'auto',
  id: 'twtr-widget',
  theme: {
```

Comment: How to perform this without using an iframe? can you explain further?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).  Your script can't pull in other scripts from a different domain.

To work around it you could simply move the twitter load into the page, rather than as part of the Ajax.

```
// stick this in your page <head>
<script src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script>

// then this can be loaded via Ajax.
<script>
new TWTR.Widget({
  // ...
}).render().setUser('gtteam').start();
</script>
```

Comment: I get different an eternal looping error though, `widget...6460501 (line 12)
attempt to run compile-and-go script on a cleared scope
[Break On This Error] if(!window.twttr){window.twttr={}}(fun...cument.attachEvent("onclick",A)}}})();`

Answer (score 0):

Load your twitter widget async using jQuery; download and run the 'widget.js' script using getScript() jQuery API as
...lets make red twitter widget async, ready?

```
$.getScript
(
    "http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js",
    function () 
        {
            makeTwitterWidget();
        }
);
```

'makeTwitterWidget()' is your function to create the twitter instance as:

```
function makeTwitterWidget() {
new TWTR.Widget
    (
        {
            version: 2,
            type: 'profile',
            rpp: 3,
            interval: 3000,
            width: 'auto',
            height: 300,
            id: 'twtr-widget',
            theme:
        {
            shell:
                {
                    background: '#ff0000',
                    color: '#ffffff'
                },
            tweets:
                {
                    background: '#ffffff',
                    color: '#000000',
                    links: '#ff0000'
                }
        },
            features:
            {
                scrollbar: false,
                loop: true,
                live: true,
                hashtags: true,
                timestamp: true,
                avatars: false,
                behavior: 'default'
            }
        }
    ).render().setUser('gtteam').start();
```

}

[You can make custom twitter widget at](http://twitter.com/about/resources/widgets/widget_list) http://twitter.com/about/resources/widgets/widget_list